# Communicating between child components - Trigger and change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a 'settings' component that will be used to change the text and background colour of another component, however I am unsure of the best way to go about it.

I know how to change the styles of the text and background if they were contained within the same component, I'm just not sure of the communication between different components.

I have a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/communicate-between-child-components) with my example code

**app.component.html**

```
<settings></settings>
<my-comp></my-comp>
```

**my-comp.component.html**

```
<div #textDiv>
  <p>This is the component where the text and background will change colour</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis.</p>
</div>
```

**settings.component.html**

```
<div class="container" [ngClass]="{expanded: toggled}">
  <a class="material-icons" (click)="toggle()">settings</a>
  <div>
    <button (click)="changeTextColour()">Change text</button>
    <button (click)="changeBackgroundColour()">Change BG</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**settings.component.ts**

```
export class SettingsComponent  {
  toggled = false;

  toggle() {
    this.toggled = !this.toggled;
  }

  changeTextColour() {
    // Do something
  }

  changeBackgroundColour() {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

### update

I have since attempted to get a service to work, but it doesn't appear to have gone well.

**service.ts**

```
export class SettingsService {
  text = new Subject();

  setColour(colour) {
    this.text = colour;
  }

  get getColour(): Observable<any> {
    return this.text;
  }
}
```

**settings.ts** - *Set the colour from the component*

```
constructor(private settings: SettingsService) {}

  changeTextColour() {
    this.settings.setColour('green');
  }
```

**my-comp.ts** - *subscribe to colour changes*

```
@ViewChild('textDiv')
  private text: ElementRef;

  constructor(private service: SettingsService) {
    this.service.getColour.subscribe(res => {
      this.text.nativeElement.style.background = res;
    });
  }
```

Comment: You could use a service: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/communicate-between-child-components-jt2p5s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a service to communicate between the components. All you have to do is create an observable in the service, then you can emit the changes in one component and subscribe to the change in the other component. The angular Docs explains it here https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service.

**Based on the update**

**service.ts**

```
export class SettingsService {
  text = new Subject<string>();

  colourChanged$ = this.text.asObservable();

  setColour(newColour) {
    this.text.next(newColour);
  }
}
```

**settings.component.ts**

```
constructor(private settings: SettingsService) {}
  changeColour() {
    this.settings.setColour('green');
  }
```

**my-comp.ts**

```
@ViewChild('textDiv') private text: ElementRef;
subscription: Subscription;
constructor(private settings: SettingsService) {
    this.subscription = settings.colourChanged$.subscribe(
      colour=> {
        this.text.nativeElement.style.background = colour;
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using two independent components as i see , you should use service to communicate between these 2 components.

create a service with BehaviourSubject with two functions as you need and subsribe to them in the other component.

**[`DEMO STACBKBLITZ`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-service-ch3b9x?file=app%2Fdemo-b%2Fdemo-b.component.ts)**